# UIScrollView not scrolling at all

Tags: ios

I have a composite structure of view controllers - parent view controller's view has a hole in it where I embed other view of another view controller.
I use addChildViewController and then add that child view to my view.

Now the tricky part - that view has UIScrollView and it refuses to scroll. I have made that UIScrollView in Xib, by embedding two other views in it.

I have checked frame and contentSize of that scrollView, and everything is normal, content size is big, frame is actual.

In viewDidLoad I use this:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(3000, 3000);
```

I have tried setting delegate, userInteractionEnabled, scrollingEnabled but none of these helped. I have tried setting all superviews UserInteractionEnabled and such, but it didn't help too.

I have a feeling that it is a bug with Xcode, and I might just make scrollview in code, but this pisses me off, since I have huge hierarchy of labels and it will be hard to make them in code.

I use ios5 and no autolayout.
I tried changing background color to green and I can see the scrollview on screen, it is on correct place.

Comment: are you implementing UIscroll view using paging technique?

Comment: To be sure, have you checked the autolayout attribute on your view controller?

Comment: Have you declared your scrollView as a property?

Comment: have you ever tried to enable scroll:
scrollView.ScrollEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using paging then use

```
self.scrollV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollV.frame.size.width *kNumberOfPages, 220);
self.scrollV.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollV.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollV.scrollsToTop = NO;
self.scrollV.delegate = self;
```

Here you can use number of pages to show.But before this please set delegate `UIScrollViewDelegate` of UIScroll view to that class. Please also check autolayout in your view too.

Hope this helps.